# Flask_restx List of Nested Of Polymorph

Tags: python, marshmallow, flask-restx

I wanted to create a flask_restx schema that can parse something of the following:

```
"rules": [
    {
      "rules": [
        {
          "value": "gg"
        },
        {
          "value": "Tenant Name"
        }
      ],
      "rule_type": "TENANT"
    },
    {
      "rules": [
        {
          "operator": "CONTAINS",
          "value": "gg"
        }
      ],
      "rule_type": "DEVICE_NAME"
    },
]
```

Which is basically a list of rules, that each rule is a JSON with rule_type and a smaller list of rules. The smaller list of rules are corresponding to the rule_type (as you can see different rule_types has different rules fields, `value` vs `value, operator`

Seems like I need a List of nested values, which each nested value is a Polymorph (can be a list of rules of different types corresponding to the rule_type).
Does this thing exist in flask_restx?

I know that list of nested is possible, but I'm not able to create a list of nested of polymorphs.